# Does the first season of The Expanse cover the entire first book?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, the-expanse-2015, the-expanse-novels, leviathan-wakes, calibans-war

I've seen the first season of *The Expanse*. I haven't read any of the books (yet). I expect there to be differences between the book and the TV series, as will happen always.

**But do the first season of the *The Expanse* TV series and *Leviathan Wakes*, the first book of the series, cover the same period and events?**

Or are there events in the book not yet covered in the show?
Or perhaps events in the show taken from the second book, *Caliban's War*?

Comment: Sorry for slightly off-topic comment.  I loved the books, but not yet looked into the TV series.  Is the TV series any good, or is it better to stick with the books? The next book, "Babylon's Ashes", is due out on the 8th Dec by the way.

Comment: @Pete The TV series is quite well done.  There are some minor changes from the books, but nothing major (so far).  I started reading the books after watching the show, so perhaps my perspective is tainted; I find if I read a book first, the show/movie never live up to my expectations.

Comment: @Pete while I appreciate the discussion, that is a question in its own right. Although you'd have to formulate it a bit differently for it not to be closed as opinion based.

Comment: @Trenin Thanks. SQB - My apologies.

Comment: @Pete, for what it's worth, I read and initially didn't particularly care for the first book (and hadn't planned to read any others).  Tried, and binged, the show - thought it was great.  Then reread the first book (loved it, no idea what I was thinking before) and the rest of the series.  And FYI I'm usually a book over TV/movies person.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first season covers about the first half of *Leviathan Wakes*.  There are definitely events in the first book that have not yet happened on the show.

However, there are also components of the show that did not occur in the first book.  For example:

> Chrisjen Avasarala is not in the first book. She makes her debut in *Caliban's War*, book 2 of the series.

Answer (score 2):

Some things from the series are heavily 'modified' from the books. For example, in the books Alex never kept it secret that he was in the Martian navy.

Comment: I don't think he really hides it in the movie - it comes out about 2nd episode.