# In The Expanse, which books follow the end of the TV show?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, the-expanse-2015, the-expanse-novels

There are 6 seasons and 9 books -- does each book roughly equal to 1 season? Does this mean you can basically jump into book 7 if you have watched the show, but haven't read the books?

Does the story in the books diverge from the show?

Comment: I'd read them all. Lot better than the TV show.

Comment: I wouldn't skip any of the books, character development is suitably different between the show and the books that you might be lost with regard to the later motivations of some characters.  Also, if you skip the early books, you skip some things which the show simply left out - vomit zombies for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Book 7 (*Persepolis Rising*) would be the next one to read to continue where the show left off. The series finale of the show is titled ["Babylon's Ashes"](https://expanse.fandom.com/wiki/Babylon%27s_Ashes_(episode)) (which is the title of the sixth book) and covers the end of that book.

In general, season N of the show corresponded mostly with book N of the series, though in some cases the season started/ended at a slightly different point as the book (e.g. [the end of the first season / beginning of the second did not match the end of the first book and beginning of the second](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/145730/31936)). The story in the show was generally faithful to the story in the books so you should have no problem jumping straight to the seventh book after watching all seasons of the show. The show also included some tidbits from some of the novellas (e.g. the last season of the show included some elements from the novella ["Strange Dogs"](https://expanse.fandom.com/wiki/Strange_Dogs)). The main difference between the show and the books has to do with [changed character storylines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/240769/31936).

Comment: Wouldn't call it that faithful, and as time progressed, it got only worse. Once they prematurely killed off Alex so they could fire the actor, I just gave up.

Comment: @DanMašek The show was faithful enough that you can pick up the seventh book and understand what's going on without too much trouble, which is the question here.

Comment: @Null I disagree with that - in *general* and large plot points you might be correct, but character development differs substantially between the show and books that you wont get a lot of references from later books.  See the difference between the two for the character Camina Drummer for example.